# Нужна ли запятая после слова "выбирайте"?

Tags: пунктуация

**Выбирайте, где вам удобнее заниматься.**
Или:
**Выбирайте где вам удобнее заниматься.**

Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Она отделяет придаточное от главного.

Comment: Благодарю, интуиция не подвела)) Но правил не помню уже.

Comment: Правила можете найти здесь. http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_...aksis_i_punktuaciya/